# Mouse pointer gets stuck on "something" on the left edge of the screen

Tags: mouse, touchpad

When I move my mouse pointer to the left side of the screen to use the launcher panel, it sticks momentarily. I won't be able to move the mouse pointer. It just gets stuck on the edge for ~3 seconds before it magically teleports to the general direction I was trying to move it. It happens over and over again exclusively on the left edge of the screen.

I'm on 16.10

Anyone experienced this before? Any solutions?

Thanks!

Comment: I am also facing same problem. Specially when I use double screens.